# How to search for @ before : in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have some lines like that

```
aaaaa:bbbbb
cccc@yahoo.com:hjgg
dddd:ggfdgfg@hotmail.com
```

I want to search for the lines that has the character `@` before `:` not `@` after `:`

In other words search should result the line `cccc@yahoo.com:hjgg` only

Comment: The search clause should be `@.*:`
Don't forget to enable the regex search.

You also can use `^[^:@]*@[^:@]*:[^:@]*$` to search for lines with exact one doublecolon and one 'at' symbol.

Comment: @Mark You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

In regexes, that would be `\@.*?\:`

If you want to exclude spaces between @ and : `\@\S*?\:`

Comment: In Notepad++ the escape character `\\` is not needed. But your regex works OK +1

Comment: It is not needed in any regex flavor. Still, regex allows escaping any non-word character to get its literal meaning, since it's not always obvious if it needs escaping (is special for a regex)

Answer (score 1):

The search clause should be `@.*:`

Don't forget to enable the regex search.
You also can use `^[^:@]*@[^:@]*:[^:@]*$` to search for lines with exact one doublecolon and one 'at' symbol.